# how to get multiple column indexes that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have data like below:

```
   id  attribute1  attribute2  attribute3  attribute4  attribute5   new  otherattri
0   1           1           0           0           0           0     1           2
1   2           1           1           1           1           0  1234          12
2   3           0           0           0           0           1     5          21
3   4           1           0           1           0           0    13          93
4   5           0           0           0           1           0     4           2
```

The column called `new` is what I want to calculate. What should I do to achieve this in pandas?  The new column simply combines the previous 5 columns in the dataframe into a new column, e.g. for line 4, attribute1 == 1 and attribute3 == 1, so the new column for line4 is 13.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to makes it look better, but it seems Markdown table is not working here...

Comment: if you have a dataframe you can use `print(df.to_string())` to paste a table here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.dot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df1=df.loc[:,df.columns[:-2]] #omitting the last 2 columns for reproducibility
df1['new']=df1.dot(df1.columns.str.replace('attribute',''))
print(df1)
```

---

```
    attribute1  attribute2  attribute3  attribute4  attribute5   new
id                                                                  
1            1           0           0           0           0     1
2            1           1           1           1           0  1234
3            0           0           0           0           1     5
4            1           0           1           0           0    13
5            0           0           0           1           0     4
```

Comment: Note: This is assuming `id` is an index, if not set the index as id before proceeding

Answer (score 1):

you can also create a function to do an activity and apply it to the dataframe using

```
.apply()
```

```
def conattr(c):
    a=''
    for i in range (1,6):
        a+=(str(i) if (c['attribute'+str(i)]>0) else '') #conditionally concatenating index values
    return a


df['new'] = df.apply(conattr,axis=1)
```